# Ocultar ou Ofuscar SRC de iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Opa,

Preciso ocultar o código src do iframe em html, tentei da seguinte forma alteralo

`$('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.site.com/');`

Sem sucesso, como posso ocultar ou ofuscar o src do iframe?

Vlw

Comment: Qual o objetivo?

Comment: Solicitação de cliente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta se propõe ofuscar (dificultar) o código src do iframe em html, visto que é impossível ocultar.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script src="a.js"></script>

 <iframe src="javascript:;" id="myframe"></iframe>
```

> **Arquivo JS (a.js)**
>
> Em primeiro lugar copie o código abaixo cole no seu editor de texto e substitua o URL.

```
  $('#myframe').attr('src', 'http://dominio.com');
```

> Vá até [javascript obfuscator](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx) e cole o código para que seja "ofuscado". Não esqueça de limpar o campo antes de colar o código lá.
>
> Feito isto, deverá retornar algo parecido com:

```
 var _0x5a5d=["\x73\x72\x63","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x6B\x69\x74\x68\x6F\x6D\x65\x70\x61\x67\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x23\x6D\x79\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65"];$(_0x5a5d[3])[_0x5a5d[2]](_0x5a5d[0],_0x5a5d[1])
```

> Finalmente, componha seu a.js da seguinte forma:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var _0x5a5d=["\x73\x72\x63","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x6B\x69\x74\x68\x6F\x6D\x65\x70\x61\x67\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x23\x6D\x79\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65"];$(_0x5a5d[3])[_0x5a5d[2]](_0x5a5d[0],_0x5a5d[1])
   });
```

Comment: Mas mesmo assim ele ainda continua sendo exibido. Ele só não vai exibir durante o carregamento, mas durante a execução a URL vai estar lá

Comment: Se usar o `alert(_0x5a5d);` ele entrega o resultado. Mas, acredito que isto é o mais próximo que pode chegar, a outra única alternativa seria utilizar proxy.

Comment: @Inkeliz é verdade, mas poucos sabem desse recurso e não acredito que sNniffer vá colocar um alert na pagina dele kkkkkk, nem comentar isso com seu cliente!!!

Comment: Não tenho flash, mas o iframe é para `http://petecasaofrancisco.com/Inkeliz.html`? Basta dar um `view-source:` depois ir em `http://kithomepage.com/sos/ocultar-src.js` e copiar o `_0xc407`, depois F12 > `alert(_0xc407)`. Uma outra forma, no F12 é ver no `iframe` o `src`. Uma outra forma é simplesmente `alert($('iframe').attr('src'))`.